# Quadrado magico em android

Tags: java, android

Queria fazer um quadrado magico, onde coloco 9 números, e a soma deles tem que resultar 15(nas diagonais, horizontais e verticais) estou fazendo no android studio . só tenho isso até então:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    final EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    final EditText ET3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET3);
    final EditText ET4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET4);
    final EditText ET5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET5);
    final EditText ET6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET6);
    final EditText ET7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET7);
    final EditText ET8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET8);
    final EditText ET9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET9);
    Button BT1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BT1);
    Button BT2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BT2);

    BT2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                ET1.setText("");
                ET2.setText("");
                ET3.setText("");
                ET4.setText("");
                ET5.setText("");
                ET6.setText("");
                ET7.setText("");
                ET8.setText("");
                ET9.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.diego.teste.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BT2"
    android:layout_width="118dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:text="@string/limpa"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/BT1"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:text="@string/verifica"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET1"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.529"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ET9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="194dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET8"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ET9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET5"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET9"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="194dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ET8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ET6"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar , na parte de retirada de números das variáveis, soma e verificação?

Comment: alguem consegue me ajudar , na parte de retirada de numeros das variaveis, soma e verificação?

Comment: A soma de cada diagonal, linha e coluna tem de dar `15` é isso ?

Comment: é tipo um enigma, o objetivo de quem tentar é que todas as direções a soma dê 15. ai tem um botão de verificação que diz se esta correto ou n ; e o botão para limpar todos os edittext.() o de limpar eu ja fiz

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma flexível e organizada de achar as somas é utilizando arrays bidimensionais representando uma grelha. Para isso será necessário pegar em cada valor dos `EdiText` e interpretar como inteiro com `Integer.parseInt` e colocar na casa respetiva. Depois com `fors` pode-se percorrer cada linha, coluna e diagonal e confirmar se o total é o esperado:

```
public boolean verificarQuadrado(int total){
    EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    EditText ET3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET3);
    EditText ET4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET4);
    EditText ET5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET5);
    EditText ET6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET6);
    EditText ET7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET7);
    EditText ET8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET8);
    EditText ET9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET9);

    int[][] numeros = {
        { 
            Integer.parseInt(ET1.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET2.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET3.getText().toString())
        },
        { 
            Integer.parseInt(ET4.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET5.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET6.getText().toString())
        },
        { 
            Integer.parseInt(ET7.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET8.getText().toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(ET9.getText().toString())
        }   
    };

    for (int  i = 0; i < numeros.length; ++i){
        int linha = 0, coluna = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; ++j){
            linha += numeros[i][j];
            coluna += numeros[j][i];
        }

        if (linha != total || coluna != total)
            return false;
    }

    int diag1 = 0, diag2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; ++i){
        diag1 += numeros[i][i];
        diag2 += numeros[i][numeros.length-i-1];
    }

    return diag1 == total && diag2 == total;
}
```

Este método `verificarQuadrado` devolve `true` se o quadrado mágico tem o total pretendido ou `false` caso contrário. Por isso apenas tem de o utilizar assim:

```
if (verificarQuadrado(15)) { //ou if(verificarQuadrado(15) == true)
    //código para quando o usuário ganhou
}
```

Note que eu assumi que os `EditText` estão posicionados da seguinte forma:

```
-------------------
| ET1 | ET2 | ET3 |
-------------------
| ET4 | ET5 | ET6 |
-------------------
| ET7 | ET8 | ET9 |
-------------------
```

Para além disso o algoritmo de verificação não usa nenhum tamanho fixo e por isso irá funcionar para um quadrado magico 3x3, 4x4 ou maior, desde que inicie o array bidimensional apropriadamente.

---

Observação: A partir da API 26 não precisa da conversão quando faz o `findViewById`, e por isso quando vai buscar um elemento ao layout:

```
EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET1);
```

Pode passar a faze-lo como:

```
EditText ET1 = findViewById(R.id.ET1);
```

Que é mais simples e menos chato de escrever.

Comment: Ajudou bastante obrigado